# getting Ceil() of Decimal in python?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding, ceil

Is there a way to get the ceil of a high precision Decimal in python?

```
>>> import decimal;
>>> decimal.Decimal(800000000000000000001)/100000000000000000000
Decimal('8.00000000000000000001')
>>> math.ceil(decimal.Decimal(800000000000000000001)/100000000000000000000)
8.0
```

math rounds the value and returns non precise value

Comment: I'm new to python, just started out yesterday in fact. Stumbled upon this problem in my second practice program (the first was of course the obligatory "print 'Hello, World!';"). so, I'm finding it difficult to judge the best answer to this. The decimal.Context solution by Matthew Flaschen worked in my particular case.
But I'd like others to upvote the best solution (also would be helpful for newbies like me if you can explain why a certain approach works better) and I'll come back and accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = decimal.Decimal('8.00000000000000000000001')
with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec=100000000000000000
    ctx.rounding=decimal.ROUND_CEILING
    y = x.to_integral_exact()
```

Comment: This is good, but there's no need to change the context precision here.  `to_integral_exact` also takes a `rounding` argument, so you can avoid messing with the context altogether.

Answer (score 35):

The most direct way to take the ceiling of a Decimal instance `x` is to use `x.to_integral_exact(rounding=ROUND_CEILING)`.  There's no need to mess with the context here.  Note that this sets the `Inexact` and `Rounded` flags where appropriate;  if you don't want the flags touched, use `x.to_integral_value(rounding=ROUND_CEILING)` instead.  Example:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_CEILING
>>> x = Decimal('-123.456')
>>> x.to_integral_exact(rounding=ROUND_CEILING)
Decimal('-123')
```

Unlike most of the Decimal methods, the `to_integral_exact` and `to_integral_value` methods aren't affected by the precision of the current context, so you don't have to worry about changing precision:

```
>>> from decimal import getcontext
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
>>> x.to_integral_exact(rounding=ROUND_CEILING)
Decimal('-123')
```

By the way, in Python 3.x, `math.ceil` works exactly as you want it to, except that it returns an `int` rather than a `Decimal` instance.  That works because `math.ceil` is overloadable for custom types in Python 3.  In Python 2, `math.ceil` simply converts the `Decimal` instance to a `float` first, potentially losing information in the process, so you can end up with incorrect results.

Comment: Just for completeness: in python 2.x `math.ceil` doesn't work as expected: it converts decimal to float first. Because of that `int(ceil(D('1.0000000000000001')))` evaluates to 1 in python 2.x and to 2 in python 3.x

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: Thanks, good point.  I've edited that information into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the precision and rounding mode option of the Context constructor.

```
ctx = decimal.Context(prec=1, rounding=decimal.ROUND_CEILING)
ctx.divide(decimal.Decimal(800000000000000000001), decimal.Decimal(100000000000000000000))
```

EDIT:  You should consider changing the accepted answer..  Although the `prec` can be increased as needed, `to_integral_exact` is a simpler solution.

Comment: perfect :) --- completing character limit ---

Comment: @Alex sorry had to leave before 6 minute timeout. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: -1.  This doesn't generalize well;  it only happens to work in this case because the result is in the range [1, 10].  Try the same calculation with Decimal(123)/Decimal(10), for example, and you'll get a result of `Decimal('2E+1')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> decimal.Context(rounding=decimal.ROUND_CEILING).quantize(
...   decimal.Decimal(800000000000000000001)/100000000000000000000, 0)
Decimal('9')
```

Comment: Note that this solution has problems for `Decimal` instances with large value:  e.g., if you try `c.quantize(decimal.Decimal('1e100'), 1)` with your context `c`, you'll get an `InvalidOperation` exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
def decimal_ceil(x):
    int_x = int(x)
    if x - int_x == 0:
        return int_x
    return int_x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use potency to make this.
import math

```
def lo_ceil(num, potency=0): # Use 0 for multiples of 1, 1 for multiples of 10, 2 for 100 ...
      n = num / (10.0 ** potency)
      c = math.ceil(n)
      return c * (10.0 ** potency)

lo_ceil(8.0000001, 1) # return 10
```