# Dividing large numbers in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to divide some large numbers in Python but i'm getting some strange results

```
NStr = "7D5E9B01D4DCF9A4B31D61E62F0B679C79695ACA70BACF184518" \
       "8BDF94B0B58FAF4A3E1C744C5F9BAB699ABD47BA842464EE93F4" \
       "9B151CC354B21D53DC0C7FADAC44E8F4BDF078F935D9D07A2C07" \
       "631D0DFB0B869713A9A83393CEC42D898516A28DDCDBEA13E87B" \
       "1F874BC8DC06AF03F219CE2EA4050FA996D30CE351257287" 

N = long(NStr, 16)
f2 = 476

fmin = N / float(f2)

print N - (fmin * float(f2))
```

This outputs as `0.0` as expected. However if I, for example, change the code to

```
fmin = N / float(f2)
fmin += 1
```

I still get an output of `0.0`

I also tried using the decimal package

```
fmin = Decimal(N) / Decimal(f2)
print Decimal(N) - (fmin * Decimal(f2))
```

But that gives me an output of `-1.481136900397802034028076389E+280`

I assume i'm not telling python how to handle the large numbers properly, but i'm stumped on where to go from here.

I should also add that the end goal is to calculate

```
fmin = ceil(N / float(f2))
```

as a long and as accurate as possible

Comment: Is `f2` always going to be an integer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, if `N` and `f2` are `long`s strictly greater than 0, then

```
 fmin = (N - 1) // f2 + 1
```

is exactly `ceil(N / float(f2))` (but even more accurately than using floats).

(The use of `//` rather than `/` for integer division is for compatibility with Python 3.x for no extra effort.)

It is because `N // f2` gives you (basically) `floor(N / float(f2))` and so `N // f2 + 1` is almost always the same as `ceil`. However, when `N` is a multiple of `f2`, `N // f2 + 1` is too large (the `+1` shouldn't be there) but using `N - 1` fixes this, and doesn't break the other case.

(This doesn't work for either `N`, `f2` less than or equal to 0, but that can handled separately)

Answer (score 4):

`fmin` is a `float` after you divide the long integer by a float. Its value is `1.84952718165824e+305`. Adding 1 to that doesn't change it at all, the precision is simply not that high.

If you do integer division instead, `fmin` remains a `long`:

```
>>> fmin = N / f2
>>> fmin
18495271816582402193321106509793602189617847415669131056768139225220221855498293
49983070478076000952025038039460539798061570960870927236986153971731443029057201
52035339202255934728764897424408896865977423536890485615063959262845076766281553
766072964756078264853041334880929452289298495368916583660903481130L
>>> N - (fmin * f2)
111L
```

Of course, you're not getting `0` because of the integer division where the decimal part of the result is discarded.
But now, adding 1 *will* make a difference:

```
>>> N - ((fmin+1) * f2)
-365L
```

Using the `Decimal` module doesn't change the problem:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> fmin = Decimal(N) / Decimal(f2)
>>> fmin
Decimal('1.849527181658240219332110651E+305')
```

There still is no unlimited precision, and even if you set `Decimal.getcontext().prec = 2000`, you still wouldn't get exactly 0.

Comment: This is not the behaviour I see on python 2.7.2

Comment: This is what I see on Python 2.7.2 (Windows 7 x64, 64-bit version of Python). What are you using?

Comment: So if I wanted to do `fmin = math.ceil(N / f2)` and get the answer back as a long but to the highest degree of accuracy as possible what would I do?

Comment: The same. To be clear: the issue I am seeing is not the one you identify. It is that subtracting the float from the long yields 0. I am preparing an answer.

Comment: @NathanBaggs, `fmin = ((N - 1) // f2) + 1` (Both `N` and `f2` are positive `long`s)

Answer (score 3):

If you need precision, avoid floating point arithmetic altogether. Since python has arbitrary-precision integers, you can calculate the ceiling of the division using basic integer arithmetic. Assuming the dividend and divisor are both positive, the way to do that is to add divisor - 1 to the dividend before dividing. In your case:

```
fmin = (N + f2 - 1) / f2
```

On Python 3.x use the `//` operator instead of `/` to get integer division.

Answer (score 2):

`Fraction` from the [`fractions`](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) module might be useful:

```
>  : N = Fraction(N)   
>  : f2 = Fraction(f2)
>  : fmin = N / f2
>  : print N-f2*fmin
0
>  : fmin += 1
>  : print N-f2*fmin
-476
```

But if your only goal is to calculate `ceil(N / float(f2))` you can use:

```
>  : fmin = N/f2 + int(ceil((N % f2) / float(f2)))
>  : print fmin
184952718165824021933211065097936021896178474156691310567681392252202218554982934998307047807600095202503803946053979806157096087092723698615397173144302905720152035339202255934728764897424408896865977423536890485615063959262845076766281553766072964756078264853041334880929452289298495368916583660903481131
```

Comment: Does math.ceil(N / float(f2)) give the same result, if not why?

Comment: @NathanBaggs: No it won't. As others have pointed out, when you convert to float you are losing information. That's before the `ceil` call. In any case, `ceil` will return a float, so there again. Same problem.

Comment: `int(ceil((N % f2) / float(f2)))` is overly complicated for the task it's doing: how about `(1 if N % f2 else 0)`?

Answer (score 1):

Floats simply don't have enough precision for this kind of operations.

You can improve the precision of the `decimal` module with `getcontext()`. For example to use 65536 decimal places:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 2**16
```

Then:

```
>>> print Decimal(N) - (fmin * Decimal(f2))
-2E-65228
```

Still not 0 but closer :)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2796005/17911) to do a `ceil()` on a `Decimal` object.

Answer (score 1):

I also found like behaviour in python 2.7.2:

```
In [17]: N
Out[17]: 8803749384693223444020846698661754642258095369858506383021634271204825603217187705919415475641764531639181067832169438773077773745613648054092905441668
8183122792368821460273824930892091174018634908205253603559871152770444609114256540750019592650731223893254070047675403322419289706083795604293822590057017991L

In [18]:

In [18]: (fmin * float(f2))
Out[18]: 8.803749384693223e+307
In [19]: N - (fmin * float(f2))
Out[19]: 0.0

In [20]: (fmin * float(f2))
Out[20]: 8.803749384693223e+307

In [21]: N == (fmin * float(f2))
Out[21]: False

In [22]: N < (fmin * float(f2))
Out[22]: False

In [23]: N > (fmin * float(f2))
Out[23]: True
```

For reasons I don't understand, it seems that subtracting a float from a long yields 0.

The solution would appear to be to convert both to a `decimal.Decimal`:

```
In [32]: decimal.Decimal(N) - decimal.Decimal(fmin * float(f2))
Out[32]: Decimal('4.099850360284731589507226352E+291')
```

Comment: But if you convert both to decimal you get the wrong answer, surely it should be `0.0`

Comment: @NathanBaggs Why should it be 0? They are not equal.

Comment: if `fmin = N / f2` then `fmin * f2 = N`

Comment: @NathanBaggs No. That only holds for real numbers (and numbers that obey the same rules). If you don't believe me, look at what python says: `N > (fmin * float(f2))` yields `True`.